# Superset Error: How to remove "31" in x-axis? (See picture below)

Tags: apache-superset

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD11A.png)

Superset Error: How to remove "31" in x-axis? (See picture above). When the time column is set to Day as shown in picture. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp4bf.png) "31" is shown in the x-axis.

Superset Error: How to remove "31" in x-axis? (See picture above). When the time column is set to Day as shown in picture. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp4bf.png) "31" is shown in the x-axis.